# Python Application that Always Listen to Specific Port Number

Tags: python, sockets, service, port

I want to create a python application that is always listening to a parametrized port. Whenever there is a request coming from the port, the application will parse the request and do tasks based on the request.

Is this type of application called services? (I have 0 knowledge on services). Where can I find beginner's tips and guides on this type of development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_%28computing%29), there are examples at the bottom of the Python [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) documentation page.

HTH.

Comment: @hocl is server & service applications are the same things?

Comment: From my understanding `service` is what you offer and `server` is who offers it, but I'm not an English native speaker so this info may be wrong. Anyways, here is what the page says: "Servers often provide essential services across a network, ". So `ssh` or `ftp` would qualify as a service (as listed in `/etc/services` on *nix).

Comment: so if the application is like this: it is always running and automatically started when Windows is booted. However, the application may take command from either command line (ex: `app print_receipt 100`) or some request over the network (ex: `localhost:<port_rumber>/print_receipt`. Does this type application is both server and service?

Comment: I'd say it's a `server` that offers a service, i.e. the service is `backdoor service that executes commands over the network` and the program is the `windows trojan server` ...

Answer (score 3):

This is [socket programming](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html). Writing sockets is cumbersome, you can use any web server written in python. My recommendation is use [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), it is very simple. Meanwhile have a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) which is built on top of werkzeug.

In case you are trying to build your own protocol engine [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) is one which will help you to  achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

You can using threads or the [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) (arguably an easier option) framework to create a server.